# Does a smooth homeomorphism of closed manifolds preserve cobordism fundamental class?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, cobordism

Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map of closed oriented smooth manifolds which is also a homeomorphism.  Let $[M]\in H_\bullet(M;\mathbb Z)$ denote the fundamental class (and similarly for $N$).  It is clear that $f_\ast[M]=N$.  Is the same true if $[M],[N]$ instead denote the fundamental classes in oriented bordism?

Comment: The statement after "it is clear that" is false (take an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, e.g.). Other than that, the statement is true, and also in cobordism where it is even trivially true if you define cobordism theory geometrically.

Comment: @Dylan: please read questions carefully before you vote to close. User35353 wrote ''smooth map which is also a homeomorphism'' and not ''diffeomorphism'' (in the latter case, the answer is indeed trivial). It is a nontrivial question and I would like to see a qualified answer (which I cannot provide).

Comment: A diffeomorphism is both smooth and a homeomorphism, so I think Dylan's answer it totally pertinent. Besides, I don't think he voted to close since I did and so far there's only one vote. I can't see a non-trivial part in the question, and I think it's completely answered by Dylan.

Comment: @Fernando : For a diffeomorphism, the inverse is also smooth.  Not so with a smooth homeomorphism.

Comment: All diffeomorphisms are smooth homeomorphisms, aren't they? Anyway, smoothness is irrelevant for thisquestion I think. The up votes and your comments make me think that I may be terribly mistaken, but so far I can't see how.

Comment: @JohannesEbert: I did not vote to close...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (not being an expert on cobordism), but isn't the definition that $M$ and $N$ are cobordant if there is a manifold $W$ and a diffeomorphism $\partial W \cong M \amalg N$?  If $M \cong N$ then we can take $W = M \times [0,1]$.  But here we're asking for if $f \colon M \to N$ is a smooth homeomorphism **not necessarily a diffeomorphism** (eg $x \mapsto x^3$).  So you'd need to adjust the cobordism to take that into account.  One thing that would give it would be if whenever $f \colon M \to N$ was a smooth homeomorphism then there was a diff $g \colon M \to N$.

Comment: Oriented bordism is a generalized cohomology theory. The n-dimensional group of a topological space X is the set of maps M -> X from oriented smooth manifolds M modulo cobordism. The fundamental class of a manifold is represented by the identity map.

Comment: @Dylan: sorry for the allegation.

Comment: I think the question is difficult. Here are my reasons: 1. it is true that homeomorphic manifolds are oriented cobordant, even if they are not diffeomorphic. This requires, to my knowledge, two fields medal theorems: Thom and Wall did prove that two oriented smooth manifolds are cobordant if their Pontrjagin numbers and Stiefl-Whitney numbers agree. The Stiefel-Whitney numbers are homotopy invariants, because you can express then in terms of the Spivak normal fibration and the Steenrod operations. The Pontrjagin numbers are invariant under homeomorphisms by Novikov's famous result.

Comment: So, already the question whether the images of the fundamental classes in $\Omega_{\ast} (pt)$ are the same is nontrivial. 2: from undergraduate analysis, it is known that a smooth homeomorphism does not need to be a diffeomorphism. In fact, if I am not mistaken, there exist smooth homeomorphism between exotic spheres. Let $M$ be an exotic sphere. By the solution of the highdimensional Poincare conjecture, there is a homeomorphism $S^n \to M$ which is everywhere smooth, except in one point. Now pick a homeomorphism of $R^n$ that is smooth, regular outside the origin and whose $\infty$-jet

Comment: at $0$ is $0$. Composing with such a homeomorphism (in appropriate charts) creates a smooth homeomorphism between exotic spheres (it is of course not a diffeomorphism).

Comment: Last but not least: any proof attempt that does not refer to special structural properties of oriented cobordism is doomed to fail. There exists exotic spheres that are not spin cobordant to the standard sphere. This means that the result is wrong for spin bordism.

Comment: Now I see the problem for bordism! Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X$ be an oriented $d$-manifold, and consider the homomorphism
$$\rho_i : \Omega_d(X) \to H^{4i}(X;\mathbb{Z})$$
which sends $f : M \to X$ to $f_!(p_i(TM))$, the pushforward along $f$ of the $i$th Pontrjagin class of $M$. This is cobordism-invariant by the usual argument.

Now $\rho_i(id_M) = p_i(TM)$, and if $f : N \to M$ is a homeomorphism then $\rho_i(f) = (f^{-1})^*(p_i(TN))$.

So if the cobordism fundamental class were homeomorphism invariant, the integral Pontrjagin classes would be. This is false cf. chapter 4.4 of the Novikov conjecrure book by Kreck and Lueck.

Comment: Thanks!  If two smooth manifolds are homeomorphic are they necessarily related by a smooth homeomorphism? (maybe this is hard in general, but maybe one can at least say something for one of the counterexamples to the homeomorphism invariance of integral Pontryagin classes).